# Extract values from entry cells on website to excel

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, html, data-extraction

I have a table on a webpage with **entry cells and drop down menus**, and I can't seem to find a way to extract that to an excel worksheet.

I have used the following code:

```
Sub ExtractGEO()

Dim objWeb As QueryTable

Set objWeb = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
Connection:="URL;http://globalenergyobservatory.org/geoid/40540", _
Destination:=Range("A1"))

With objWeb

    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebTables = "3" ' Identify your HTML Table here
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
'
End Sub
```

But this only extracts the headers, not the values written in the entry cells nor the selected values on the dropdown menus.
I am not at all familiar with HTML, so I do not understand how this information is not extracted when extracting the tables. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Excel QueryTable is not so flexible as you need. Consider IE automation, or XHR response parsing. You need get collection of all table rows and process each cell, including extraction of data from `input` and `select` tags.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. This returns all the data on the website. You will have to look into to different ways to of trapping the data you need.

```
Sub ExtractGEO()

' Requires a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0

Dim oXH             As Object
Dim sURL            As String
Dim bodytxt         As String

On Error GoTo errorHandler

sURL = "http://globalenergyobservatory.org/geoid/40540"

Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

With oXH
.Open "get", sURL, False
.Send
 bodytxt = .responseText
End With

Msgbox  bodytxt

Debug.Print bodytxt

errorHandler:

Set oXH = Nothing

End Sub
```

I hope that helps if you want me to make an example of using IE extraction method i will just ask. Id tends to be much slower. Only issue with the method i wrote above is you are limited on the amount of times you can make the call. You may never hit is bit if you do there are work rounds.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example showing how to retrieve HTML content via XHR, parse it with RegExp and output to the worksheet:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sPayLoad As String
    Dim sContent As String
    Dim aData()

    ' Retrieve general info
    sUrl = "http://globalenergyobservatory.org/geoid/40540"
    sContent = GetXHR(sUrl)
    aData = ParseData(sContent)
    ' Output to Sheet1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        Output .Cells(1, 1), aData
    End With
    ' Retrieve performance data
    sUrl = "http://globalenergyobservatory.org/geoutility.php"
    sPayLoad = "type=Gas&op=performance&did=40540&StartYear=2000&EndYear=2009"
    sContent = PostXHR(sUrl, sPayLoad)
    aData = ParseData(sContent)
    ' Output to Sheet2
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        Output .Cells(1, 1), aData
    End With

    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Function GetXHR(sUrl As String) As String

    ' GET XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .Send
        GetXHR = .responseText
    End With

End Function

Function PostXHR(sUrl As String, sPayLoad As String) As String

    ' POST XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", sUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sPayLoad)
        .Send CStr(sPayLoad)
        PostXHR = .responseText
    End With

End Function

Function ParseData(sContent As String) As Variant()

    Dim cRows As Object
    Dim oRow
    Dim sRowContent As String
    Dim cCells As Object
    Dim oCell
    Dim sCellContent As String
    Dim cItems As Object
    Dim oItem
    Dim sSubMatch
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim aItems()
    Dim aRows()
    Dim aData()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Create dictionary for rows
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Get row nodes <tr> RegEx matches collection
        Set cRows = RegExMatches(sContent, "<tr[^>]*?/>|<tr[^>]*?>(.*?)</tr>")
        ' Process each rows in collection
        For Each oRow In cRows
            ' Get row HTML content
            sRowContent = oRow.SubMatches(0)
            ' Get cell nodes <th> and <td> RegEx matches collection
            Set cCells = RegExMatches(sRowContent, "<td[^>]*?/>|<t([hd])[^>]*?>([\s\S]*?)</t\1>")
            ' Create dictionary for cell items
            With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                ' Process each cell in collection
                For Each oCell In cCells
                    ' Get cell HTML content
                    sCellContent = oCell.SubMatches(1)
                    ' RegEx patterns combined:
                    ' <input type="text"[^>]*?value="([^"]*?)"[^>]*?> - textbox value
                    ' <input type="checkbox"[^>]*?checked="checked">([^<]*?)</input> - checked box
                    ' <input type="radio"[^>]*?checked="(checked)"/> - checked radio
                    ' <label[^>]*?>([^<]*?)</label> - label text
                    ' <span[^>]*?>([^<]*?)(?=<) - text within span
                    ' <select[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<option[^>]*?selected="selected">([^<]*?)</option> - dropdown value
                    ' ^[^<>]* - plain text
                    ' Get the below cell items RegEx matches collection
                    Set cItems = RegExMatches(sCellContent, _
                        "<input type=""text""[^>]*?value=(""[^""]*?"")[^>]*?>|" & _
                        "<input type=""checkbox""[^>]*?checked=""checked"">([^<]*?)</input>|" & _
                        "<input type=""radio""[^>]*?checked=""(checked)""/>|" & _
                        "<label[^>]*?>([^<]*?)</label>|" & _
                        "<span[^>]*?>([^<]*?)(?=<)|" & _
                        "<select[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<option[^>]*?selected=""selected"">([^<]*?)</option>|" & _
                        "^([^<>]*)" _
                        )
                    ' Process each item in collection
                    For Each oItem In cItems
                        ' Create dictionary for item submatches
                        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                            ' Add combined patterns submatches to dictionary
                            For Each sSubMatch In oItem.SubMatches
                                .Item(.Count) = sSubMatch
                            Next
                            ' Convert dictionary to array and join array elements, then trim result string
                            sItem = Trim(Join(.Items(), ""))
                        End With
                        ' Nonempty string add to cell items dictionary
                        If sItem <> "" Then .Item(.Count) = sItem
                    Next
                Next
                ' Convert cell items dictionary to array of cell items
                aItems = .Items()
            End With
            ' Nonempty array of cell items add to row dictionary
            If UBound(aItems) >= 0 Then .Item(.Count) = aItems
        Next
        ' Convert rows dictionary to rows array
        ' Rows array contains nested cell items arrays for each matched item in row
        aRows = .Items()
    End With
    ' Convert nested arrays into 2d array for output
    ' ReDim the first dimension only once
    ReDim aData(1 To UBound(aRows) + 1, 1 To 1)
    ' Copy values for each row and cell
    For j = 0 To UBound(aRows)
        aItems = aRows(j)
        For i = 0 To UBound(aItems)
            ' Expand the second dimension if necessary
            If i + 1 > UBound(aData, 2) Then ReDim Preserve aData(1 To UBound(aRows) + 1, 1 To i + 1)
            aData(j + 1, i + 1) = aItems(i)
        Next
    Next
    ' Return 2d array
    ParseData = aData

End Function

Function RegExMatches(sText As String, sPattern As String, Optional bGlobal = True, Optional bMultiLine = True, Optional bIgnoreCase = True)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = bGlobal
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = sPattern
        Set RegExMatches = .Execute(sText)
    End With
End Function

Sub Output(objDstRng As Range, arrCells As Variant)

    With objDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(arrCells, 1) - LBound(arrCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(arrCells, 2) - LBound(arrCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .WrapText = True
            .Value = arrCells
            .Columns.ColumnWidth = 25
            .Columns.AutoFit
            .EntireRow.AutoFit
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

For the source webpage:

[image: source]

The output for me as follows on the Sheet1:

[image: output1]

And on the Sheet2:

[image: output2]

General info and performance data are being extracted separately due to the way the webpage actually works in a browser - performance data is added to the page as DHTML from POST XHR while webpage is loading.